# Improving performance for a nested for loop iterating over dates

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy, google-bigquery

I am looking to learn how to improve the performance of code over a large dataframe (10 million rows) and my solution loops over multiple dates `(2023-01-10, 2023-01-20, 2023-01-30)` for different combinations of `category_a` and `category_b`.

The working approach is shown below, which iterates over the dates for different pairings of the two-category data by first locating a subset of a particular pair. However, I would want to refactor it to see if there is an approach that is more efficient.

My input (`df`) looks like:

|  | date | category_a | category_b | outflow | open | inflow | max | close | buy | random_str |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-10 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 0 | a |
| 1 | 2023-01-20 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 20 | nan | nan | a |
| 2 | 2023-01-30 | 4 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 20 | nan | nan | a |
| 3 | 2023-01-10 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 0 | b |
| 4 | 2023-01-20 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 20 | nan | nan | b |
| 5 | 2023-01-30 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | nan | nan | b |

with 2 pairs `(4, 1)` and `(4,2)` over the days and my expected output (`results`) looks like this:

|  | date | category_a | category_b | outflow | open | inflow | max | close | buy | random_str |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-10 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 10 | -1 | 23 | a |
| 1 | 2023-01-20 | 4 | 1 | 2 | -1 | 23 | 20 | 20 | 10 | a |
| 2 | 2023-01-30 | 4 | 1 | 10 | 20 | 10 | 20 | 20 | nan | a |
| 3 | 2023-01-10 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 10 | -2 | 24 | b |
| 4 | 2023-01-20 | 4 | 2 | 2 | -2 | 24 | 20 | 20 | 0 | b |
| 5 | 2023-01-30 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 20 | 20 | nan | b |

I have a working solution using pandas dataframes to take a subset then loop over it to get a solution but I would like to see how I can improve the performance of this using perhaps ;`numpy`, `numba`, `pandas-multiprocessing` or `dask`. Another great idea was to rewrite it in BigQuery SQL.

I am not sure what the best solution would be and I would appreciate any help in improving the performance.

***Minimum working example***

The code below generates the input dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# prepare the input  df
df = pd.DataFrame({
'date' : ['2023-01-10', '2023-01-20','2023-01-30', '2023-01-10', '2023-01-20','2023-01-30'] ,
'category_a' : [4, 4,4,4, 4, 4] ,
'category_b' : [1, 1,1, 2, 2,2] ,
'outflow' : [1.0, 2.0,10.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0],
'open' : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] ,
'inflow' : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] ,
'max' : [10.0, 20.0, 20.0 , 10.0, 20.0,  20.0] ,
'close' : [0.0, np.nan,np.nan, 0.0, np.nan, np.nan] ,
'buy' : [0.0, np.nan,np.nan, 0.0, np.nan,np.nan],
'random_str' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'] 
})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# get unique pairs of category_a and category_b in a dictionary
unique_pairs = df.groupby(['category_a', 'category_b']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})[['category_a', 'category_b']].to_dict('records')
unique_dates = np.sort(df['date'].unique())
```

Using this input dataframe and Numpy, the code below is what I am trying to optmizize.

```
df = df.set_index('date')
day_0 = unique_dates[0] # first date

# Using Dictionary comprehension

list_of_numbers = list(range(len(unique_pairs)))
myset  = {key: None for key in list_of_numbers}

for count_pair, value in enumerate(unique_pairs):
    
    # pair of category_a and category_b
    category_a = value['category_a']
    category_b = value['category_b']

    # subset the dataframe for the pair
    df_subset = df.loc[(df['category_a'] == category_a) & (df['category_b'] == category_b)]

    log.info(f" running for {category_a} and {category_b}")

    # day 0
    df_subset.loc[day_0, 'close'] = df_subset.loc[day_0, 'open'] + df_subset.loc[day_0, 'inflow'] - df_subset.loc[day_0, 'outflow']
    
    
    # loop over single pair using date
    for count, date in enumerate(unique_dates[1:], start=1):
        previous_date = unique_dates[count-1]

        df_subset.loc[date, 'open'] = df_subset.loc[previous_date, 'close']
        df_subset.loc[date, 'close'] = df_subset.loc[date, 'open'] + df_subset.loc[date, 'inflow'] - df_subset.loc[date, 'outflow']

        # check if closing value is negative, if so, set inflow to buy for next weeks deficit

        if df_subset.loc[date, 'close'] < df_subset.loc[date, 'max']:
            df_subset.loc[previous_date, 'buy'] = df_subset.loc[date, 'max'] - df_subset.loc[date, 'close'] + df_subset.loc[date, 'inflow']
        elif df_subset.loc[date, 'close'] > df_subset.loc[date, 'max']:
            df_subset.loc[previous_date, 'buy'] = 0
        else:
            df_subset.loc[previous_date, 'buy'] = df_subset.loc[date, 'inflow']
        
        df_subset.loc[date, 'inflow'] = df_subset.loc[previous_date, 'buy']
        df_subset.loc[date, 'close'] = df_subset.loc[date, 'open'] + df_subset.loc[date, 'inflow'] - df_subset.loc[date, 'outflow']
    
    # store all the dataframes in a container myset
    myset[count_pair] = df_subset
    
# make myset into a dataframe
result = pd.concat(myset.values()).reset_index(drop=False)
result
```

After which we can check that the solution is the same as what we expected.

```
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

expected = pd.DataFrame({
'date' : [pd.Timestamp('2023-01-10 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-01-20 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-01-30 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-01-10 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-01-20 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-01-30 00:00:00')] ,
'category_a' : [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4] ,
'category_b' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2] ,
'outflow' : [1, 2, 10, 2, 2, 0] ,
'open' : [0.0, -1.0, 20.0, 0.0, -2.0, 20.0] ,
'inflow' : [0.0, 23.0, 10.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0] ,
'max' : [10, 20, 20, 10, 20, 20] ,
'close' : [-1.0, 20.0, 20.0, -2.0, 20.0, 20.0] ,
'buy' : [23.0, 10.0, np.nan, 24.0, 0.0, np.nan] ,
'random_str' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'] 
})

# check that the result is the same as expected
assert_frame_equal(result, expected)
```

***SQL to create first table***

The solution can also be in sql, if so you can use the following code to create the initial table.

I am busy trying to implement a solution in big query sql using a user defined function to keep the logic going too. This would be a nice approach to solving the problem too.

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 
    DATE '2023-01-10' as date, 4 as category_a, 1 as category_b, 1 as outflow, 0 as open, 0 as inflow, 10 as max, 0 as close, 0 as buy, 'a' as random_str
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    DATE '2023-01-20' as date, 4 as category_a, 1 as category_b, 2 as outflow, 0 as open, 0 as inflow, 20 as max, NULL as close, NULL as buy, 'a' as random_str
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    DATE '2023-01-30' as date, 4 as category_a, 1 as category_b, 10 as outflow, 0 as open, 0 as inflow, 20 as max, NULL as close, NULL as buy, 'a' as random_str
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    DATE '2023-01-10' as date, 4 as category_a, 2 as category_b, 2 as outflow, 0 as open, 0 as inflow, 10 as max, 0 as close, 0 as buy, 'b' as random_str
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    DATE '2023-01-20' as date, 4 as category_a, 2 as category_b, 2 as outflow, 0 as open, 0 as inflow, 20 as max, NULL as close, NULL as buy, 'b' as random_str
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    DATE '2023-01-30' as date, 4 as category_a, 2 as category_b, 0 as outflow, 0 as open, 0 as inflow, 20 as max, NULL as close, NULL as buy, 'b' as random_str
)

SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) as " ",
  date,
  category_a,
  category_b,
  outflow,
  open,
  inflow,
  max,
  close,
  buy,
  random_str
FROM data
```

Comment: `df_temp` is not set. What it is supposed to be? I I set it to `df.copy()` I get many errors. Can you make this code fully reproducible?

Comment: Hi @JérômeRichard, thanks for pointing that out. `df_temp` is `df`, I had made a mistake while preparing the code but it's fixed now.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I still got the issue: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`. Is this the consequence of what you mean by "use data frame slices"?

Comment: @JérômeRichard, I think it just means a slice is subset of the data is taken then manipulated. That manipulated piece is then placed as an element of the list. That is what the code does.

Comment: Maybe instead of looping over t, set the date to the index then loop over dates in the index. That would allow you to 1st loop over the pair then second loop over dates for each pair. Implicitly you have a nested for loop.

Comment: Also perhaps switching this nested for loop to numba or cython, it would still run on one core though, so you could also use dask.

Comment: Yes @JérômeRichard, you are right. It is a consequence of that.

Comment: Thanks @user849541, I made that change and used the date as the index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Efficient algorithm

First of all, **the complexity of the algorithm can be improved**. Indeed, `(df['category_a'] == category_a) & (df['category_b'] == category_b)` travels the whole dataframe and this is done for each item in `unique_pairs`. The running time is `O(U R)` where `U = len(unique_pairs)` and `R = len(df)`.

An efficient solution is to perform a **groupby**, that is, to split the dataframe in `M` groups each sharing the same pair of category. This operation can be done in `O(R)` time where `R` is the number of rows in the dataframe. In practice, Pandas may implement this using a (comparison-based) sort running in `O(R log R)` time.

---

### Faster access & Conversion to Numpy

Moreover, **accessing a dataframe item per item using `loc` is very slow**. Indeed, Pandas needs to locate the location of the column using an internal dictionary, find the row based on the provided date, extract the value in the dataframe based on the ith row and jth column, create a new object and return it, not to mention the several check done (eg. types and bounds). On top of that, Pandas introduces a significant overhead partially due to its code being interpreted using typically CPython.

A faster solution is to **extract the columns ahead of time**, and to **iterate over the row using integers** instead of values (like dates). The thing is the order of the sorted date may not be the one in the dataframe subset. I guess it is the case for your input dataframe in practice, but if it is not, then you can sort the dataframe of each precomputed groups by date. I assume all the dates are present in all subset dataframe (but again, if this not the case, you can correct the result of the `groupby`). Each column can be **converted to Numpy** so to the can be faster. The result is a pure-Numpy code, not using Pandas anymore. Computationally-intensive Numpy codes are great since they can often be heavily optimized, especially when the target arrays contains native numerical types.

Here is the implementation so far:

```py
df = df.set_index('date')
day_0 = unique_dates[0] # first date

# Using Dictionary comprehension

list_of_numbers = list(range(len(unique_pairs)))
myset = {key: None for key in list_of_numbers}

groups = dict(list(df.groupby(['category_a', 'category_b'])))

for count_pair, value in enumerate(unique_pairs):
    
    # pair of category_a and category_b
    category_a = value['category_a']
    category_b = value['category_b']

    # subset the dataframe for the pair
    df_subset = groups[(category_a, category_b)]

    # Extraction of the Pandas columns and convertion to Numpy ones
    col_open = df_subset['open'].to_numpy()
    col_close = df_subset['close'].to_numpy()
    col_inflow = df_subset['inflow'].to_numpy()
    col_outflow = df_subset['outflow'].to_numpy()
    col_max = df_subset['max'].to_numpy()
    col_buy = df_subset['buy'].to_numpy()

    # day 0
    col_close[0] = col_open[0] + col_inflow[0] - col_outflow[0]

    # loop over single pair using date
    for i in range(1, len(unique_dates)):
        col_open[i] = col_close[i-1]
        col_close[i] = col_open[i] + col_inflow[i] - col_outflow[i]

        # check if closing value is negative, if so, set inflow to buy for next weeks deficit
        if col_close[i] < col_max[i]:
            col_buy[i-1] = col_max[i] - col_close[i] + col_inflow[i]
        elif col_close[i] > col_max[i]:
            col_buy[i-1] = 0
        else:
            col_buy[i-1] = col_inflow[i]

        col_inflow[i] = col_buy[i-1]
        col_close[i] = col_open[i] + col_inflow[i] - col_outflow[i]
    
    # store all the dataframes in a container myset
    myset[count_pair] = df_subset

# make myset into a dataframe
result = pd.concat(myset.values()).reset_index(drop=False)
result
```

This code is not only faster, but also a bit easier to read.

---

### Fast execution using Numba

At this point, the general solution is to use vectorized functions but this is really not easy to do that efficiently (if even possible) here due to the loop **dependencies** and the conditionals. A fast solution is to use a JIT compiler like **Numba** so to generate a very-fast implementation. Numba is designed to work efficiently on natively-typed Numpy arrays so this is the perfect use-case. Note that Numba need the input parameter to have a well-defined (native) type. Providing the types manually cause Numba to generate the code eagerly (during the definition of the function) instead of lazily (during the first execution).

Here is the final resulting code:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('(float64[:], float64[:], float64[:], int64[:], int64[:], float64[:], int64)')
def compute(col_open, col_close, col_inflow, col_outflow, col_max, col_buy, n):
    # Important checks to avoid out-of bounds that are 
    # not checked by Numba for sake of performance. 
    # If they are not true and not done, then 
    # the function can simply cause a crash.
    assert col_open.size == n and col_close.size == n
    assert col_inflow.size == n and col_outflow.size == n
    assert col_max.size == n and col_buy.size == n

    # day 0
    col_close[0] = col_open[0] + col_inflow[0] - col_outflow[0]

    # loop over single pair using date
    for i in range(1, n):
        col_open[i] = col_close[i-1]
        col_close[i] = col_open[i] + col_inflow[i] - col_outflow[i]

        # check if closing value is negative, if so, set inflow to buy for next weeks deficit
        if col_close[i] < col_max[i]:
            col_buy[i-1] = col_max[i] - col_close[i] + col_inflow[i]
        elif col_close[i] > col_max[i]:
            col_buy[i-1] = 0
        else:
            col_buy[i-1] = col_inflow[i]

        col_inflow[i] = col_buy[i-1]
        col_close[i] = col_open[i] + col_inflow[i] - col_outflow[i]

df = df.set_index('date')
day_0 = unique_dates[0] # first date

# Using Dictionary comprehension

list_of_numbers = list(range(len(unique_pairs)))
myset = {key: None for key in list_of_numbers}

groups = dict(list(df.groupby(['category_a', 'category_b'])))

for count_pair, value in enumerate(unique_pairs):
    # pair of category_a and category_b
    category_a = value['category_a']
    category_b = value['category_b']

    # subset the dataframe for the pair
    df_subset = groups[(category_a, category_b)]

    # Extraction of the Pandas columns and convertion to Numpy ones
    col_open = df_subset['open'].to_numpy()
    col_close = df_subset['close'].to_numpy()
    col_inflow = df_subset['inflow'].to_numpy()
    col_outflow = df_subset['outflow'].to_numpy()
    col_max = df_subset['max'].to_numpy()
    col_buy = df_subset['buy'].to_numpy()

    # Numba-accelerated computation
    compute(col_open, col_close, col_inflow, col_outflow, col_max, col_buy, len(unique_dates))

    # store all the dataframes in a container myset
    myset[count_pair] = df_subset

# make myset into a dataframe
result = pd.concat(myset.values()).reset_index(drop=False)
result
```

Feel free to change the type of the parameters if they do not match with the real-world input data-type (eg. int32 vs int64 or float64 vs int64). Note that you can replace things like `float64[:]` by `float64[::1]` if you know that the input array is contiguous which is likely the case. This generates a faster code.

Also please note that `myset` can be a list since `count_pair` is an increasing integer. This is simpler and faster but it might be useful in your real-world code.

---

### Performance results

The Numba function call runs in about 1 µs on my machine as opposed to 7.1 ms for the initial code. This means the hot part of the code is **7100 times faster** just on the tiny example. That being said, Pandas takes some time to convert the columns to Numpy, to create groups and to merge the dataframes. The former takes a small constant time negligible for large arrays. The two later operations take more time on bigger input dataframes and they are actually the main bottleneck on my machine (both takes 1 ms on the small example). Overall, the whole initial code takes 16.5 ms on my machine for the tiny example dataframe, while the new one takes 3.1 ms. This means a 5.3 times faster code just for this small input. On bigger input dataframes the speed-up should be significantly better. Finally, please not that `df.groupby(['category_a', 'category_b'])` was actually already precomputed so I am not even sure we should include it in the benchmark ;) .

Comment: Hi @JérômeRichard ,  I see that the Numba `compute` function does not have a `return`, it is not working on my side and I was wondering if that is because of the return statement? I have changed the open, outflow and close from INT64 to FLOAT64 too since that is what they are in my function. Thank you for the response this is really nice, I just need to understand how to get it to work and go through it a few times.

Comment: All numerical columns in my case, except category_a and category_b, also could there be a step missing, where the `Numba-accelerated computation` writes to `df_subset`?

Comment: Thank you @JeromeRichard, I realised that Numba needs the missing values to be `0.0` in the float columns for the calculations to work. Thank you this is great :D

Comment: Indeed, the types need to match so if you change them, you can have errors like this. I guess this is fine now. Regarding the `return`, it is not required here sine the computation is done in-place. If you want an out-of-place computation, you can just do a copy before but copies are expensive (like out-of-place computations).